# React Native Expo - Open my app from android browser when clicking a link

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to implement a link on my website **that opens my Android App when clicked in the browser from the phone**.

I can send them to Google Play from the app with

```
Linking.openURL("market://details?id=com.myapp.android")
```

and from my website I can send them to the same page with a link as
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.android

But **I want it to open the app itself if is already installed**. Is this possible? If so, how?

**EDIT**

[Expo Linking](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/linking.html) says all I have to do is add

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "myapp"
  }
}
```

to my `app.json` and then enter the scheme value in my browser

However, I tried this and then entered

> myapp://

in my browser, but it just sent me to a google seach with this as keywords.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It now works.

When I enter myapp:// in the chrome or samsung browser in my phone, it sent me to a google search. However, i added an

```
<a href="myapp://">open app</a>
```

it worked flawlessly.

Note that you also have to add

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "myapp"
  }
}
```

to your **app.json**

If your app is still in development in the expo client, you should use a link such as

```
exp://76-6zc.myexpouser.my-app-name.exp.direct:80
```

this is the link you will see in the CMD or terminal when you run exp start command. Read more [here at the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#linking-to-your-app)